# Cannot change background image of main window

Tags: qt

I am new to QT, and have been having some trouble changing the background image of the main window. My code results in the compilation of the program but without any image.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/res/images/background.png);");

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you add this file to resource, are you sure that it is correct path?

Comment: Yeah, my resources directory is `MyFiles.qrc`, `pics`, `background.png`

Comment: You can try `Run qmake` and then `Rebuild`. This will run again your moc's files to meet the changes on the resources.

Answer (score 3):

**An example**

**1 -** Create a resource file (or open an existing one).

[image]

**2 -** Add your background image under a prefix.

[image] In this case the prefix is "/".

**3 -** Save

**4 -** Now you are able to use the resource in your style sheet.

```
this->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/res/bkg.png);");
```

**5 -** Rebuild and run.

***Remarks***: Remember that style sheets are cascaded. So in your case the main window and all its children will use that background unless other is specified at a lower level. You have to be aware of that and use selectors properly if more control is required.

Comment: This basically answered my question. I incorrectly referenced the `res` file. But don't include a forward slash in the resource filename; that's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

No need to reference the `qrc` file. Remove `/res` in the following line:

```
this->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/res/images/background.png);");
```

The result is:

```
this->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/background.png);");
```

Answer (score 0):

or

```
ui->centralWidget->setStyleSheet("background-image: url(:/images/background.png);");
```

if your trying to change the ui